permission denied error with Linkedin API `peopleTypeahead`
We do have the rw_organization_admin scope permissions for Linkedin but we get permission denied error with
{"status"=>403, "serviceErrorCode"=>100, "code"=>"ACCESS_DENIED", "message"=>"Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiPeopleTypeaheadExternal.FINDER-organizationFollowers.20240101"}


According to the LinkedIn Docs, you need the r_organization_followers permission, and not rw_organization_admin.
Additionally, ensure the user is an administrator for the organization:

Restricted to organizations in which they are authenticated.
ADMINISTRATOR
DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER


unauthorized_scope_error | Scope 'r_organization_followers' is not authorized for your application this is the error message I get back from Linkedin Callback after adding r_organization_followers to scope

@Sathish you should have this permission appear in your developer app, under OAuth 2.0 scopes. You get permissions by requesting more products.
